# How to compare Random Forest with other models

Tags: neural-network, random-forest, ensemble-modeling

I am new to Machine Learning and I am trying to undrestand the Out of Bag Error in Random Forests and its use.

Let's say that we have a dataset. First we use the whole dataset (without splitting it) to get a Random Forest and its Out of Bag error. Then we split the dataset, train a Neural Network on the training part and test it on the test part of the dataset.

Can I choose between the two models by comparing the Out of Bag error of the random forest with the total test error of the Neural Network ? Does it make sense ?

Comment: if you are new to machine learning maybe you should start with non-neural networks.

Comment: Just do the split in the same way. Separate test set, or multiple ones (cross validation), is good practice also with Random Forest

Comment: @jonnor thanks.. ok what you suggest is clear.. but then how can I make use of the out of bag error of a random forest ?

Comment: @nnd my question applies also to non-neural networks though.. please advise for this case then

Comment: read about model selection
 https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html

Comment: @batman you do not need out-of-bag estimates in that case. The test set split gives your performance estimate instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally rely on sampling to validate the result of our Model.

 We make train/test to test a model on a separate unseen dataset.

 If we are doing a Hyperparameter tuning, we keep another set as a validation set to validate the result of new hyperparameters.

Random forest builds each new tree on a *Bagged sample* from the original sample(train data).

Bagging means sampling is done with replacement *i.e. you pick one data point, put it back and then pick the next*.

In this process, many duplicated data is sampled and many data points are not sampled.

*~63% of the data points are selected* [Read here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88980/why-on-average-does-each-bootstrap-sample-contain-roughly-two-thirds-of-observat)

The other "not selected" 37% data points is called Out of Bag samples.

*Hence, the way Bagging, and RF is designed, we got another set of data to do our validation. It an opportunity to do a level of validation with these samples.*

What it means,

- You are getting 37% data points to validate your model
- But OOB is not done with the fully grown Ensemble. *It is done using all the trees in the random forest ensemble for which the particular data point was omitted during training* [Read here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13151/randomforestclassifier-oob-scoring-method)
- It's not equivalent to K-Fold or Train/test on fully built RF but it gives a decent idea about the validation error about to come.